# Collatz Conjecture (c++)

Tags: c++, beginner, collatz-sequence

I am new to C++ and this is my first program. The objective of this program is to fully complete the sequence called the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

> It concerns a sequence defined as follows: start with any positive integer n. Then each term is obtained from the previous term as follows: if the previous term is even, the next term is one half the previous term. Otherwise, the next term is 3 times the previous term plus 1. The conjecture is that no matter what value of n, the sequence will always reach 1.

I am not familiar with the language just yet and would appreciate some (constructive) feedback. The program works as intended, however, I have a feeling that some of my code is not as elegant as it could/should be.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

bool isValid(int num) {
  if(num <= 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

bool isEven(int num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

void calculate(int num) {
  if (num == 1) {
    cout << endl << "Finished!" << endl;
    return;
  } else if(isEven(num)) {
    num = num / 2;
    cout << num << " ";
    calculate(num);
  } else {
    num = (num * 3) + 1;
    cout << num << " ";
    calculate(num);
  }
}

int main() {

  int input;
  cout << "Please enter an integer greater than zero." << endl;
  cin >> input;

  if(isValid(input)) {
    calculate(input);
  } else {
    cout << "Not a valid input." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Has anyone tried running this with 715827883 or higher? :)

Comment: 113383 is also apparently a very interesting number to run this program with

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good job checking the input for validity and breaking up the logic into simple functions! However, some improvements can be made.

### [Avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3964927)

This can cause name collisions because it adds every name in the `std` namespace to the global namespace. For a small program like this one it's unlikely that you'll run into any problems (then again, [maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593548/3964927)) but it's best to get into the habit of using the `std::` prefix on names in the `std` namespace.

Alternatively, you can introduce [using declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) like `using std::cout;` to add specific names to the global namespace.

### Avoid `std::endl` in favor of `\n`

[`std::endl` flushes the stream, which can cause a loss in performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/3964927) In some cases you can also reduce calls to `operator<<` (e.g. `cout << endl << "Finished!" << endl;` becomes `cout << "\nFinished!\n";`).

### Simplify your boolean expressions

You can remove some of your explicit `return true` and `return false` statements by `return`ing the expression in the `if` condition. For example, you can shorten `isEven()` like so:

```
bool isEven(int num) {
  return num % 2 == 0;
}
```

Similarly, you can shorten `isValid()`.

### Don't mix logic and writing to `cout` in `calculate()`

Currently `calculate()` is not very reusable since it writes to `cout`. What if you wanted to write to a different stream, or if you just wanted to calculate the next term in the sequence without writing to *any* stream? I suggest redefining `calculate()` to simply return the next term in the sequence:

```
int next(int prev) {
  if (isEven(prev))
    return prev / 2;
  else
    return prev * 3 + 1;
}
```

Then in `main()` you can output each number returned by `next()` to `cout`, as well as check for the condition in which the term equals 1. You would replace the `calculate(input);` statement in `main()` with something like this:

```
while (input != 1) {
  input = next(input);
  std::cout << input << " ";
}

std::cout << "\nFinished!\n"
```

Comment: I fixed the `next` function to not rely on a global variable, and the loop to terminate. I hope it matches your style.

Comment: Can't say I agree with the part about std::endl.  If you want to see your output or logs as they happen, its essential to use endl.  It can be very confusing to debug a program that buffers its output.  It's good to know the implications of flushing the buffer, but if you're at the point where you're using cout to see your program flow, you need it to be as responsive as possible.

Comment: However, I do agree that the endl _before_ `"Finished!"` is unnecessary and should be a `\n`.  There's nothing to flush at that point.

Comment: @JPhi1618 The OP says the program works as intended, so I take that to mean he isn't debugging. And I don't see much point in flushing the stream for *every* term in the sequence just to see the output as it's generated. There's a time and a place for using `std::endl` to see the output as it is generated (I do it myself in certain situations) but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that the OP only flushes the stream at the end of the sequence and at a few other times (right before receiving the input and right before returning from main). It seems even more superfluous in this case since it would be flushed anyway.

Comment: I lumped writing a program only to learn with debugging in my head.  Someone just learning C++ shouldn't focus on the performance of flushing every output statement.  Sure this is a simple case, but if OP gets into the habit of always using `\n`, they will eventually be in a confusing situation when their output isn't printing for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 4):

Your error handling is missing an important point. When you declare the variable `input`, it already has a value, though that value is typically unpredictable. Reading this value from the variable invokes *undefined behavior* (that's an official term), which would make your program useless.

The operator `std::cin >> input` is not guaranteed to write a value to the variable. It only does so if the input is valid. So when I type `asdf` instead of an integer, the old value is preserved (or in general, partly overwritten, but for an `int`, that's not possible).

After that, your code reads that undefined value. It must not do this.

To solve this problem, write all code like this:

```
int input;
if (std::cin >> input && input > 0) {
  std::cout << "The number is " << input << ".\n";
} else {
  std::cerr << "error: wrong input format\n";
  return 1;   // Returning 1 from the main function means an error.
}
```

The `>>` operator does not read the value of the variable, it only writes to it in the successful case. Therefore this program never reads the undefined value from the variable.

Comment: Shouldn't you be initializing the `input` variable in your example?

Comment: No. This usage is perfect since I'm only reading the variable _after_ it has been definitely assigned a value. The `>>` operator also is a write-only operation on the variable.

Comment: Yes, nervermind, I misread your code for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Null's answer:

Very nice use (intentional or not) of tail recursion.

**Use unsigned int when you want to represent numbers greater or equal to zero**

`unsigned int` can represent twice as many numbers as `int`. It also gives the compiler more information about what your program does, which lets it do its job better.

**Do not include headers you are not using**

You are not using `<ctime>` for anything, so you should not include it.

**Return something else than 0 in main when the program fails**

The convention is that a program returns 0 on success, and something else on failure. It's generally just 1, but some programs encode the nature of the failure in that number.

```
else {
  cout << "Not a valid input." << endl;
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply testing a boolean expression and returning true or false based on the result, you could just return the result of the boolean expression.

Rather than

```
if (num % 2 == 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You could simply have

```
return num % 2 == 0;
```

since the result of `num % 2 ==0` already is a bool.

To do this with your `isValid` function, you would have to either negate the boolean expression, or change the way you are comparing the numbers.

The expression `num <= 0` would become `!(num <= 0)`, which might be a little more confusing, or simply change it to `num > 0`.